# How can we use proxy for connecting to dns server on requests?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

Requests doesn't resolve `nameservers` via `proxies` argument given to it by default.
How can we use make it do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Bases on requests documentation:

> Using the scheme `socks5` causes the `DNS` resolution to happen on the client, rather than on the proxy server. This is in line with curl, which uses the scheme to decide whether to do the `DNS` resolution on the client or proxy. If you want to resolve the domains on the proxy server, use `socks5h` as the scheme.

Hence we have to just set `socks5h` for the scheme of the proxy given to the `proxies` argument.